# What does || do in ( charCode < 48 || charCode > 57)?

Tags: javascript, operators

Can anyone tell me what the two lines do here?

```
( charCode < 48 || charCode > 57))
```

I guess it means something like "or" or "do both"...

```
function numberCheck(evt)
{
var charCode = (evt.which) ? evt.which : event.keyCode;
if (charCode > 31 && ( charCode < 48 || charCode > 57))
{
        document.getElementById("numonly").innerHTML = "Numbers Please!";

        return false;
}
else
{
        document.getElementById("numonly").innerHTML = "";
        return true;
}
}
```

So what your saying is that the code is looking for all characters except 48-57?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Expressions_and_Operators#Logical_operators

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Char codes 48 to 57 represent the number keys 0 - 9

|| means OR

therefore the expression will evaluate to true for any character that is not a number.

Answer (score 2):

It is an "or". Seems like the code is looking for character that are NOT in the range of character code 48 through 57.

Answer (score 0):

Numpad not working, whith this solution

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34336660)